# Insert stored PDF files from database (MySQL) into MPDF Output

Tags: php, mysql, import, mpdf

Is there a way to import pdf files which stored in database into mpdf class instance?

As for now i can use import for certain page from file only like shown below.

```
$mpdf->SetImportUse(); 
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('testfile.pdf');
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount, 50, 50, 100, 100);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId, '', '', 100, 100);
$mpdf->Output();
```

But what if I want to import from pdf which saved in database?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: since it wants a file, you'll have to retrieve from database, write out to temp file, then feed that temp file to mpdf. yet another reason storing files in the db is not a good idea.

Comment: Oh my, what an _ugly_ documentation that package has. That looks like software style from the early 80th!

Comment: According to the documentation the answer is "no", that is not possible in a direct manner. You only have a choice to save the document in a temporary file to load it. Ugly, slow and error prone. I suggest you address the company with that feature request.

Comment: making temp file was my last option before I made this thread. But I am still waiting for other option if its possible. But it seems that's impossible. My Bad day maybe :D

Answer (score 0):

Reading large files from a database is a bad idea, you'll find storing them somewhere on the file-system to be much faster. But, any file stored in the database should be stored in its' original form (possibly base64 encoded). Pretend the value you get from the database is the return from [fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and it should work fine.

Comment: Actually it appears you are right, that might be possible. Wow. Could you please add some details how that can be done?

Comment: The output from `fread()` is a string, so look through the library's documentation for parsing a string rather than a file. If the library does not currently support this method, then you can either try and add the functionality or switch to a different lib.

Comment: Ok, that is not the answer I expected. I thought you could explain how to use a database query result handle as handle for fread()... Suggesting to use another library is not an answer to the question, is it? Nor is modifying the library. Sorry.

Comment: The point is that no matter what, your return from the database is  string. You library already imports the file as a string. All you need to do is skip the part where is tries to read the file. **More than likely,** the library already supports this, and you only need to find the right function. Alternatively, you can write the output to a file and then tell your library to read that file. beyond this and everything else that was said, **there are no other options.**

Comment: Thanks for answerring.
The problem is I cant save incoming data as file in database sever host, they only give me access to mysql database server. While in webserver itself (separated from database sever of course) my space is so limited. 
And I know there is some part from library that pass string variable from result of reading file function. Its just I am having headache just from my current job, I don't want to add more headache by modifying other people library. 
Before I made this thread, I was thinking about making temporary file as you explain. But I am still waiting for another option

Answer (score 0):

Little bit later, but maybe this help somebody else.

With MPDF 8 and later:

Method  `SetSourceFile` accept string (filename) **OR StreamReader**. The `StreamReader` can be created from file **OR from string**.

So your code will looks like:

```
// $mpdf->SetImportUse(); is not supported in MPDF 8
$data = ''; // your data, NOT base64
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile(\setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader::createByString($data));
for ($i=1; $i<=$pagecount; $i++) {
  $import_page = $mpdf->ImportPage($i, 50, 50, 100, 100); // OR just: $import_page = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
  $mpdf->UseTemplate($import_page);
  if ($i < $pagecount) {
    $mpdf->AddPage();
  }
}
$mpdf->Output();
```

**Note:**

You can always call `WriteHTML` before or after or inside for cycle.